# Rails still hitting old database IP, even after restarting apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I have a Rails app on a windows machine that also has a SQLServer that it used to use as it's database.

However I am trying to transition the app to use a new SQL server on a different Windows machine.

1. The new Machine is reachable (ping)
2. After changing the database.yml file with the new IP I can go into Rails console and make queries on the new machine.
3. However, Running the code still queries the local(old) database.
4. I have restarted apache.

This is driving me nuts. Why is my code still hitting the old configuration? Do I need to restart the machine completely?

Thanks

Comment: Restarting the machine might help if you have all services configured to boot on machine restart.  The issue is you need to restart your rails server.  Apache, I believe is proxying to your Rails application server.  It is unclear from your question which application server you are using, but if you restart it the changes would go into affect.  Apache restart is not required for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try printing the TARGET_ENV and the URI that you are targeting in the Ruby code. It will tell you which IP is being hit everytime.